# ¿Cómo agrupar una BD según más de un parámetro y en distintas listas?

Tags: r

Tengo una base de datos **tasa.paro** con columnas tales como "Genero" "Provincia" "Periodo" y "TasaParo"
y la consigna es la siguiente:
*Selecciona, para cada periodo, las tres provincias en las que fue menor la tasa de
paro tanto para hombres como para mujeres (por separado).*
Y el script que fui diseñando es el siguiente:

```
tasa.paro1 <- ddply(tasa.paro, .(Periodo),
                  transform, minTasaParo = min(TasaParo))
tasa.paro2 <- ddply(tasa.paro1, .(Periodo, Provincia), 
                    transform, rankMinTasaParo = rank(-minTasaParo, ties = "random"))
dlply(tasa.paro2, .(Genero), identity)

tasa.paro2[tasa.paro2$rankMinTasaParo < 4,]
```

Sin poder llegar al objetivo porque no sé en qué momento agrupar y separar.

Se agradece de antemano cualquier ayuda u orientación en el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer con la libreria "plyr" pero te recomiendo mejor usar cualquiera de estas soluciones:

Creo un ejemplo reproducible:

```
  tasa.paro<-data.frame(Periodo=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                        Genero=c("M","F","M","F","M","F","M","F","M","F","M","F","M","F","M","F"),
                        Provincia=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D"),
                        TasaParo=abs(rnorm(n = 16,mean = 0,sd = 0.2)))
```

### Solución 1

```
detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE) # Si tienes cargado el paquete plyr
library(dplyr)
```

Para los hombres:

```
tasa.paro %>%
  filter(Genero=="M") %>%
  group_by(Periodo)%>%
  mutate(ranking = rank(TasaParo,ties.method = "random"))%>%
  filter(ranking<4)
```

Para las mujeres:

```
tasa.paro %>%
  filter(Genero=="F") %>%
  group_by(Periodo)%>%
  mutate(rank = rank(TasaParo,ties.method = "random"))%>%
  filter(rank<4)
```

### Solución 2

Porque soy un amante de data.table:

```
library(data.table)

tasa.paro<-as.data.table(tasa.paro)

tasa.paro[,rank:=rank(TasaParo,ties.method = "random"),by=.(Periodo,Genero)]
```

Para los hombres:

```
tasa.paro[Genero=="M" & rank<4]
```

Para las mujeres:

```
tasa.paro[Genero=="F" & rank<4]
```

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me re sirvio!